# Rspec: helper method to detect presence of form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test that my controller helper method `honeypot_detected?` will be true if the `@params` of a form field named `birth_city` is filled in.

Do I need to use mocks in order to test this?

helpers.rb:

```
def honeypot_detected?
  @params[:birth_city].present?
end
```

helpers_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe WindowWashers::Controllers::Shared::Helpers do
.
.
.
  before(:all) { @controller = ApplicationController.new }
    context "when honeypot_detected? is called" do
      it "returns true when birth_city is storing a value" do
        #Not sure how to represent :birth_city => 'Dallas     
        expect(honeypot_detected?).to be_true
      end
    end
  end
.
.
.
end
```

Comment: Would you be able to include your `WindowWashers::Controllers::Shared::Helpers` class (and maybe any relevant code in your `ApplicationController`) in your question as well, as I'm really not sure why you've put helper methods for your `ApplicationController` here instead of just declaring them as `private` methods in the `ApplicationController` itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
context "when honeypot_detected? is called" do
  it "returns true when birth_city is storing a value" do
    instance_variable_set(:@params, {:birth_city => "Dallas"})     
    expect(honeypot_detected?).to be_true
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to this way over the example from Paul Fioravanti? (below)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're checking values stored in an instance variable, [you should be able to use `assign` to set it](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec#helper-method-that-accesses-an-instance-variable).  I'm assuming your instance variable `@params` is just a hash, in which case you probably don't need to go so far as to use a test double like you might for a more complicated object:

```
describe '#honeypot_detected?' do
  let(:honeypot_detected) { helper.honeypot_detected? }

  context 'when birth_city present in params' do
    before { assign(:params, { birth_city: "Dallas" }) } 
    it 'returns true' do
      expect(honeypot_detected).to be_true
    end
  end

  context 'when birth_city absent from params' do
    before { assign(:params, { foo: "bar" }) }
    it 'returns false' do
      expect(honeypot_detected).to be_false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Preliminary tests show:    Banana::Controllers::Shared::Helpers     honeypot_detected?
     Failure/Error: let(:honeypot_detected) {     helper.honeypot_detected? }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `let' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000106b39f50>
     # ./spec/lib/banana/controllers/shared/helpers_spec.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Would you be able to edit your original question to include the relevant `describe` block, because that error looks like you may have accidentally put a `let` statement in a `before` block, and also I think that my response may need to be changed as it seems you're not really testing a helper method in the Rails sense, but more what seems like a `private` method on a controller.

Comment: I think you attempted to edit my answer instead of your question.